# Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play

I was just trying to deploy an app on google play store and got this error.

How do I change my target api to 31. I am aware it needs to be changed in `build.gradle` file under `android/`

This is mine:

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
```

Expo has a way to add it through my app.config.js using [build properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#configuration-in-appjson--appconfigjs)

My question what do I change it to?

Comment: Change the targetSdkVersion to 31.  Right now its 30.  But really I'd update it to 32 if not 33 unless you have reason not to-  updating is a bit of a pain, may as well upgrade it as high as possible.

Comment: did ugprading the sdk version to 31 worked? I tried this but now I get more errors

Comment: @JohhanSantana did you see the answer??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `targetSdkVersion`

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
```

Comment: It is effecting on my app and build is not created. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I also getting the same issues , please update the solution