# Upgraded Expo SDK version 47 to 49 crashes during runtime

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo, version

When I upgraded Expo SDK version 47 to 49, the app worked well in development mode, but it crashes during runtime

However, when I create an APK build of my app and install it, the app fails to load and crashes. I'm seeking assistance to identify and resolve this issue promptly. Please, can anyone help me with this problem?

Here is some additional information about my environment:

Expo SDK versions: 47 (before upgrade) and 49 (after upgrade)

Operating System: Windows 11

React Native version: "0.71.3"

Expo CLI version: 0.7.3

Node.js Version: v18.17.0

The reason for upgrading to the latest Expo SDK version was to update the API to version 33. If there's an alternative approach to achieving this, please provide guidance. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to upgrade Expo SDK version by following the official guide provided on the Expo website. You can find the guide at the following link:
[Expo SDK 49 Upgrade Guide](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740).

I need to update my API version from 31 to 33. However, when I attempted to update it, I followed the guidance provided in this:
[Upgrade API Version Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73914400/your-app-currently-targets-api-level-30-and-must-target-at-least-api-level-31-to)